# NgbRating module showing abnormality and asterisk Angular 8.1.2

Tags: typescript, angular8, ng-bootstrap

I am using `NgbRating` module from `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` and i have seen the implementation on [stackblitz](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/rating/config/stackblitz.html) and implemented as it was there. After implementing it is showing abnormality like this : 
[image]

These `(*)` between every star is showing that i don't want. Here's my **`HTML`** file code :

```
<div id="about" *ngFor="let Review of Reviews" class="p-24" fxLayout="row wrap">
            <mat-card style="padding-bottom: 60px;" class="example-card">
                <mat-card-header>
                  <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
                  <mat-card-title>{{ Review.patient.full_name }}</mat-card-title>
                  <mat-card-subtitle>{{ Review.timestamp }}</mat-card-subtitle>
                </mat-card-header>
                <div class="rating">
                    Overall Rating : 
                    <ngb-rating [rate]="Review.rating"></ngb-rating>
                </div>
                <mat-card-content>
                  <p>
                    {{ Review.review }}
                  </p>
                </mat-card-content>
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                    <textarea disabled matInput placeholder="Add your comment"></textarea>
                  </mat-form-field>
                  <mat-card-actions class="card-actions">
                  <button class="respond" mat-button>Respond</button>
                </mat-card-actions>
              </mat-card>
        </div>
```

Here is my **`typescript`** file code :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { fuseAnimations } from '@fuse/animations';
import { ReviewService } from 'app/services/review/review.service';
import { Review } from 'app/models/review/review.model';
import { NgbRatingConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-review-list',
  templateUrl: './review-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./review-list.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  animations   : fuseAnimations
})
export class ReviewListComponent implements OnInit {

  Reviews : Review[];
  constructor(private ReviewService : ReviewService, private config : NgbRatingConfig) { }

  currentRate = 3.14;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.config.max = 5;
    this.config.readonly = true;
    this.Reviews = this.ReviewService.find();
    console.log(this.Reviews)
  }

}
```

And i have also added `NgbModule` in my `module.ts` file.

Comment: You should check if you have an error in the item inspector.

Comment: Nope. It's clear!

Comment: Show us all the code to review.

Comment: Shown both the files.

Comment: The conflict must be in the css.

Comment: Conflict in `SCSS` like what?

Comment: Nope. Nothing wrong with the `scss` file. It's Empty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you did not install the [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) library, which is [needed](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) with [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). You can take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvzfrc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to see what happens when Bootstrap is missing: the text `(*)` appears next to each rating star because the styling for the `sr-only` class (for screen readers) is not applied.

In [this updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nlsgsz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), the Bootstrap library is installed and the CSS is imported in `styles.css`:

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

As a consequence the styling for the `sr-only` class is applied, hiding the unwanted stars and parentheses.

If you use Angular CLI, the Bootstrap CSS can be imported in `angular.json` as suggested in [this article](https://medium.com/@oyewusioyekunle/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-your-angular-project-angular-8-6379fd6a0f46). Please note that `JQuery` and `popper.js` are not needed when using ng-bootstrap, as mentioned in [the documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#dependencies).

Yet another method is to import the Bootstrap CSS from a CDN in `index.html`. That method is used in the [code samples](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/rating/basic/stackblitz.html) provided in the ng-bootstrap documentation:

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
```

---

If you don't want to import the whole Bootstrap CSS, you can add the following code to the global CSS in your application, for example in `styles.css`, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwge8g?file=src%2Fstyles.css):

```
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, it is solving the problem but it has almost destroyed my whole design due to adding CDN link in my html file.

Comment: I updated the answer with a suggestion for the specific CSS that you can add to your application, instead of importing the whole Bootstrap CSS

Comment: Why it doesn't support decimal values?

Comment: You can take a look at [this code sample](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/rating/examples#decimal) in the ng-bootstrap documentation. It shows how to implement decimal support.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really figure out what's the error, though I use personal code to make these kinds of evals, [CODE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fg8y8g?file=app%2Frating-config.css) here:

**html:**

```
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="rate">
        <input type="radio" id="star5" name="Rating" formControlName="Rating" value="5" />
        <label for="star5" title="5 estrelas"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="Rating" formControlName="Rating" value="4" />
        <label for="star4" title="4 estrelas"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="Rating" formControlName="Rating" value="3" />
        <label for="star3" title="3 estrelas"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="Rating" formControlName="Rating" value="2" />
        <label for="star2" title="2 estrelas"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="Rating" formControlName="Rating" value="1" />
        <label for="star1" title="1 estrela"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the styles sheet:

```
.rate {
    width: fit-content;
    height: 100px;
    margin:auto;

}
.rate:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;

}
.rate:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:45px;
    color:#ccc;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}
.rate > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #ffc700;    
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: #deb217;  
}
.rate > input:checked + label:hover,
.rate > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rate > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #c59b08;
}
```

You can then retrive the values and use them as you want in the ts, for instance, I use it in a ngForm and submit it to a service witch in term passes it to my API.

Comment: If i had to do it with the custom `CSS`, `Radio buttons` or `mat-icons` i would have done it earlier.  I am just using an `Angular module` which shows perfectly fine on stackblitz but the same code works but in between stars `(*)` is showing. I want to get rid of that without using anything extra.

Comment: In that case I can't see the issue, if it works in stackblitz, it should work in your local implementation, It's probalby somenthing with your config, check the app module, the imports, see if your modules are correctly installed, that kind of thing. You can also try to see if you have any console errors or warnings, that can help.

Comment: No console errors, no module import errors & no warning. That is the problem.